# Protein Design - Target Structure Specification

Tags: amino-acids, protein-folding

I'm curious about how protein structures are defined in general, but in particular, I'm wondering how a target structure can be specified without knowing the amino acid sequence.

For example, in protein design (or from what I gather on the wikipedia page [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_designs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_design)), scientists design a 3D structure that will perform a particular function.  They then try to come up with an amino acid sequence that will fold properly into that structure.

How can a 3D structure be defined if no amino acid sequence (and hence no molecular geometry) has been determined?

Comment: You don't create some structure and then try to find the amino acids that will create it; the residues themselves are important. Generally modelling is based on known motifs. The basic steps are: model in silico, test in vitro, fail, repeat.

Comment: Hmm, how is _de novo_ protein design done?  From the article: "In de novo design the entire sequence is designed anew, based on no previous sequence"

Comment: Right, the sequence is designed anew. I also said generally.

Comment: I think that's what I was going for in my question - how can a sequence be designed anew?  I understand the idea of protein prediction - design an amino acid sequence, try to predict how it folds. But protein design is the reverse. Am I misunderstanding the meaning of "target structure"?

Comment: Afaik. they use quantum-mechanical models to calculate the active site and probably the whole enzyme structure. Enzyme designing is a very new topic and you'll need a lot of math to understand it.